# What is the use of 'import' in SystemVerilog?

Tags: library, system-verilog

Once a `package` is included, the file is compiled. Then why it is required to `import` the same `package`?

Comment: Show an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an interesting article [here](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2010/07/13/package-import-versus-include/) regarding the difference between `import` and `` `include `` when it comes to packages. I'm going to attempt to summarise it here.

When you `` `include `` a file, it is basically saying take the contents of that file and paste it at the location of the include statement. This is effectively the same behaviour as `#include` in C/C++.

Great you are thinking, now we have everything in the file, why can't we just use it? Imagine the case though where you are declaring a package in SV. If you `` `include `` a file containing a class `A` into two different packages `P` and `Q`, you are basically making a different copy of it in each package, which because of the way SV handles types will be incompatible (you now have one class called `P::A` and another called `Q::A`).

This is where `import` comes in. Unlike `` `include ``, the `import` statement does *not* copy the definitions being brought in to the file, instead it simply makes them visible. This is similar to the way the `using namespace` works in C++. Lets say you still `` `include `` the class `A` in package `P` as before. But now, rather than including A directly in package `Q`, you `import P::A` instead, both `P` and `Q` now contain the same class `P::A` instead of having two different ones.

So in summary:

- `` `include `` copies the contents of the file in making a local copy of any classes/types/etc.
- `import` doesn't copy but rather makes the existing package declarations visible in the current file.

Comment: Clear explanation, I think this may be the reason for reduced program size also? Python uses similar 'import' command and considered light yet powerful scripting language.

Comment: So in what case both import and include is used for same package ?

Comment: @tollinjose you can use both, but it is best to avoid doing so in packages. For example in your main SV file if you `include` first this will ensure everything is included in the file, but as long as you do it outside any packages/modules (e.g. at the top of the file) it wont change the scope of anything included. In this case you would still need to `import` in order to make the packages visible.

Comment: @tollinjose I think you are getting the concepts from an interpreted scripting language like Python confused with a compiled language like SystemVerilog. Files have no meaning to compiled language. A pre-processor removes all defines, ifdefs and includes from a stream of text before the compiler parses the resulting text. Python's `import`statement is more like SystemVerilog's `include` statement. Whereas `package` and `import` in SystemVerilog deal with scopes visibility of identifiers.